# Redirect shows page for a second then changes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to block access for non-admin users to certain pages. So I'm saving a value using localStorage to identify the state of the said user, but when they try to go to admin.html, that page will show for a split second then goes to the one I want them to go. So the user both got to check the page and know that page exists, how can I avoid this?

This is what I have:

CSS

```
html { visibility: hidden; }
```

JS

```
if (localStorage.getItem('Authenticationstate') === 'out') { //if its not logged in
    window.location.href = "index.html";
} else if ((localStorage.getItem('AuthenticationState')) !== 'Admin') { //if its a normal user
    window.location.href = "Dashboard.html";
}else{ // if its admin
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    createChart();
});
```

So for example, the normal or non-logged in user put "Admin" in the URL, the page Admin shows then switches back to "Dashboard" or "index" (needless to say these 2 pages are always visible, according to the type of user)

Thanks for your help

EDIT: This is a simple demo, not a serious project

Comment: I can hack your site and become an admin just by opening my console and typing `localStorage.setItem('AuthenticationState') = "Admin"` Tadaaaa

Comment: that's a nice suggestion, thanks @JeremyThille

Comment: It's because it takes time to load up HTML/CSS/JS and execute it. Anyway, you are doing it wrong. You should redirect using back-end. As @JeremyThille said - front end is user land and not secure

Comment: @Justinas unfortunately I don't have much knowledge on server side development, or better put, don't know how to link those, all I know from server side is that I;m using Tomcat edit: typo

Comment: @notPercival Then hire developer. Now you do not have any security in terms of security

Comment: @Justinas I am not building a super secure, production, commercial app-web site, it's just a personal demo, I appreciate the help though, thanks for the unsolicited "advice"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<script>` Tag into the `<head>` Tag so this code will be executed first and before the script tags in the rest of the page. this way you can redirect asap. take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: As the others have mentioned, use this method of frontend redirect only if you will not have any sensitive information, if you do then definitely change it to backend using some Role Based Authorization.

Comment: care to share an example of this type of management?